# Nginx “Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.”

Tags: linux, proxy, ssl, certificate, nginx

Recently expired my ssl certificate. To renew certificate i used certbot, but now certificate will be automatically renewed by my hosting. But before that happens I should do the redirection from http to https on the server. Can you help me with that?

systemctl status nginx.service:

```
nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: en
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2019-08-18 07:42:13 CEST; 2 days
     Docs: man:nginx(8)
  Process: 11855 ExecStop=/sbin/start-stop-daemon --quiet --stop --retry QUIT/5
  Process: 11590 ExecReload=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; -s
  Process: 27222 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (cod
  Process: 27214 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process
 Main PID: 11583 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Aug 18 07:42:11 vps685363 nginx[27222]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 fai
Aug 18 07:42:11 vps685363 nginx[27222]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 fail
Aug 18 07:42:12 vps685363 nginx[27222]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 fai
Aug 18 07:42:12 vps685363 nginx[27222]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 fail
Aug 18 07:42:12 vps685363 nginx[27222]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 fai
Aug 18 07:42:12 vps685363 nginx[27222]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 fail
Aug 18 07:42:13 vps685363 nginx[27222]: nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
Aug 18 07:42:13 vps685363 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, cod
Aug 18 07:42:13 vps685363 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-co
Aug 18 07:42:13 vps685363 systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web ser
```

nginx.conf:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {
    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

     gzip_vary on;
     gzip_proxied any;
     gzip_comp_level 6;
     gzip_buffers 16 8k;
     gzip_http_version 1.1;
     gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

default:

```
server {
    server_name domukasi.pl www.domukasi.pl;
        location / {


                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        }



    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domukasi.pl/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domukasi.pl/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}server {
    if ($host = www.domukasi.pl) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = domukasi.pl) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    server_name domukasi.pl www.domukasi.pl;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot




}
```

This error occurs on my website(domukasi.pl):

```
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

I also can not restart my nginx server.

Answer (score 1):

It's odd that you are getting a `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` error in your browser, since your `nginx`-server did not start.

It appears that some other server is already listening on ports 80 and 443, which is causing those redirects as well as making `nginx` fail to start.

In the error log you are getting

```
Aug 18 07:42:12 vps685363 nginx[27222]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 fai
Aug 18 07:42:12 vps685363 nginx[27222]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 fail
```

which indicates that `nginx` is unable to bind to those ports, which indicates that they are either already being used by another process, or that `nginx` doesn't have enough privileges to bind to those ports (since they are below 1024). I think you already have another server running on this machine which is making use of those ports.

You can check if those ports are already being used by issuing

`sudo lsof -i :80` and

`sudo lsof -i :443`

or

`sudo netstat -ltnp | grep -w ':80'` and

`sudo netstat -ltnp | grep -w ':443'`

---

Try this default file

```
##############################################
#
#   HTTP (port 80) domukasi.pl
#
##############################################

server {

    server_name domukasi.pl www.domukasi.pl;
    listen 80;

    # redirect EVERYTHING from HTTP to HTTPS
    location / {
      return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}

##############################################
#
#   HTTPS (port 443) domukasi.pl
#
##############################################

server {

    server_name domukasi.pl www.domukasi.pl;
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domukasi.pl/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domukasi.pl/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot

    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    #######################################
    # location /websocket {
    #   # proxy_http_version 1.1;
    #   proxy_read_timeout 31536000;
    #   proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    #   proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    #   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/websocket;
    # }
    #######################################

    location / {
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header  Host $host;
      proxy_set_header  Name $server_name;
      proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Host $host;
      proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Name $server_name;
      proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-IP   $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
      proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Remote-IP   $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Remote-Port $remote_port;
      proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Server-IP   $server_addr;
      proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Server-Port $server_port;
      proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/;
    }
}
```

Comment: I checked this ports. The result of the commands is a follows [link](https://imgur.com/a/jypmDTS)

What do I have to do to make everything work properly?

Comment: Apparently your server is running, so those entries in the error log may be old ones from prior attempts at getting it running. Can you really restart the service without getting new log entries? Because if yes, then it is your configuration file, which looks strange in any case. Are you really using websocket (or a similar thing) on your backend server, because that is what `proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;` hints at.

Comment: @M7six I added a cleaned up version of your `default` file

Comment: I can restart my nginx only when the code look like this [link](https://pastebin.com/AZcwLGFg). I am really beginner in this topic, so i don't know if my site uses websocket. My friend programmed that site. I don't know why, but your default file doesn't work, can you take a look in my working default?.Generally, situtation is like this, my certificate on server expired, and I didn't know how to renew it on the backend side, so i configured a service on my hosting which will automatically renew the certificate and redirect from http to htpps and i must do the same in the backend.

Comment: Your setup is a bit complex if your hoster is managing the certificates for you and you have to integrate the certificates (as well as Let's Encrypt's interactions with your server) properly into your own, custom Nginx setup. For example, I don't see any of the `managed by Certbot` lines, which are important ones because they load the certificates and manage the interactions. You need to know exactly what your hoster expects your setup to look like. It's probably better if you try to get help at https://community.letsencrypt.org. You can refer to this Stack Overflow page.